# OSX : Symbols not found for architecture i386

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glui

I have the following makefile that uses C++ and OpenGL. It was compiling at all, so I added the -m32 line in order to attempt to get it to compile in x86_64. Now I'm getting the same error but it's saying i386 instead.

What can I do to get this program to compile?

I'm running OSX 10.8, just in case that makes a difference.

Thank you all.

```
.SUFFIXES: .cpp


#Change the following two lines to reflect the locations
# of the GLUT library (.a) and includes on your system

#TOP = /pool/u/class/cs520/Mesa-7.0.3
CFLAGS  = -w -s -O2 -ansi -DSHM
XLIBS   = -lX11 -lXext -lXmu -lXext -lXmu -lXt -lXi -lSM -lICE
LIBS    = -lglut -lGLU -lGL 
#INCLS   = -I/usr/X11R/include -I/share/mesa/include   #-I$(TOP)/include
INCLS   = -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/X11/include/GL
LIBDIR  = -L/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib #-L$(TOP)/lib 

#GLUT_LIB_LOCATION=/usr/X11R6/lib
#GLUT_INC_LOCATION=/usr/X11R6/include

#CC=gcc
CC=g++
#CPPFLAGS=-I${GLUT_INC_LOCATION} #-w 
#GLLIBS=-L${GLUT_LIB_LOCATION} -lglut -lGL -lGLU
#LPATH=${GLUTPATH} 
INCS= 

libs =     ${GLLIBS}   -lm  

All: terrain 

terrain: tg.o tga.o terrain.o 
    $(CC)   $(LPATH) tg.o tga.o terrain.o  -m32 ./glui/libglui.a $(libs) -o terrain  $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) $(XLIBS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) -c -D_LINUX_ $(INCS) $*.cpp $(INCLS)

clean:
    rm *.o

tg.o: tg.cpp terrain.h tga.h glui.h 
tga.o: tga.cpp tga.h
terrain.o : terrain.cpp terrain.h
```

And I'm getting the following error.

```
g++ -c -D_LINUX_  tga.cpp -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/X11/include/GL
g++ -c -D_LINUX_  terrain.cpp -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/X11/include/GL
g++    tg.o tga.o terrain.o  -m32 ./glui/libglui.a    -lm   -o terrain  -L/usr/X11/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib  -lglut -lGLU -lGL  -lX11 -lXext -lXmu -lXext -lXmu -lXt -lXi -lSM -lICE
ld: warning: ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file tg.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): tg.oignoring file terrain.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): terrain.oignoring file tga.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): tga.o


ld: warning: ignoring file ./glui/libglui.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): ./glui/libglui.a
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [terrain] Error 1
```

Comment: "lipo -info path/to/libglui.a" should tell you if actually contains i386 and x86. It looks to me like one of those libraries isnt..

Comment: I'm getting this `lipo: archive with no architecture specification: libglui.a (can't determine architecture for it)`.

Comment: perhaps it's just for dynamic libraries and executables...

Answer (score 1):

You're compiling for MacOS X so don't use X11 but the native OpenGL Framework; the compiler/linker option is `-framework OpenGL`.

And the error you have stems from that you probably took precompiled library filed not even compiled for your particular version of MacOS X, if even MacOS X at all. No compiler switch will help you there.